# Error: `You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected.` when i use mergeMap without toPromise

Tags: rxjs

- I'm a newbie with `rxjs`.
- I'm using the `rxjs` with version `6.6.7`.
- I want to use `mergeMap` from `rxjs/operators`. But it shows an error when I don't use `toPromise`.

```
fromEvent(document, 'click')
            .pipe(
                // mergeMap(() => interval(1000).pipe(take(5)))
                mergeMap(() => interval(1000).pipe(take(5)).toPromise())
            )
            .subscribe(console.log);
```

[Don't use `toPromise` the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7j6t.png)

[Use `toPromise`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ky76.png)

Comment: Both should work the same, so the problem is going to be somewhere else. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7edxmu?devtoolsheight=60

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found the reason for my webpack.config. Sorry about my mistake.